# Publishing Failed to Azure Functions Runtime with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure-functions-runtime

I have an Azure Functions solution in Visual Studio 2017.  I can successfully publish to my online Azure subscription.  Now I'm trying to publish to a box on my local network that is running Azure Functions Runtime v2.  The Runtime is installed and configured correctly as I am able to create a test app and it runs just fine.

However, when I attempt to publish my functions app in VS 2017 to the Azure Functions Runtime site, I get an error saying 'Publishing failed' but no Output at all.

Steps I've taken:

1. I downloaded the publishing profile from Azure Functions Runtime site (on my local network)
2. I imported the profile to my azure functions app in VS 2017.
3. It attempts immediately to publish with that profile but give me the 'Publishing failed' error with no other details.

Anyone else seeing this?  Advice?